# Why is my nailboard experiment not working?

Tags: c

I wanted to simulate the distribution of n balls which fall on a nailboard with j rows into rows+1 cups. You see, the code is simpel. There are two inputs and an array which is called faecher which contains the cups. For every ball and row 0 or 1 is radnomly chosen. With this in mind I can calculate the cup. At the end it should vertically print as many # as there are balls in a cup. However it does not function properly. It does not matter which amount of balls I input it always prints just two #.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])

{
    int kugel = atoi(argv[1]);
    int reihe = atoi(argv[2]);
    int zahl;
    int faecher[reihe+1];
    for(int i=0;i <=reihe;i++){
        faecher[i]= 0;
    }
    for(int j = 1;j <= kugel;j++ ){
       for(int i = 0; i < reihe; i++){
            zahl = rand()%2;

       }
       faecher[zahl]+= 1;

    }
    for(int j=0;j <=reihe;j++){
       for(int i=1;i<=faecher[j];i++){
        printf("#");
    }
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting an exact amount of #.

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the code in a debugger to see if what you think should be happening matches what is actually happening.

Comment: @Hector234, Why the loop? : `for(int i = 0; i < reihe; i++){  zahl = rand()%2;  }`  Only need to do `zahl = rand()%2;` once.  Are you trying for something like `zahl += rand()%2;`?  In step `faecher[zahl]+= 1;`, `zahl` is only 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

`zahl = rand()%2;` just sets the column the ball will fall into to 0 or 1. What you want to do is mimic the ball moving left or right at each pin. To do that, you can use `zahl += rand() % 2;`. However, you need to initialize `zahl` to 0 for each row. So remove the current `int zahl;` declaration and, after inside the loop on `j`, insert `int zahl = 0;`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])

{
    int kugel = atoi(argv[1]);
    int reihe = atoi(argv[2]);
    // Deleted line:  int zahl;
    int faecher[reihe+1];
    for(int i=0;i <=reihe;i++){
        faecher[i]= 0;
    }
    for(int j = 1;j <= kugel;j++ ){
        int zahl = 0;  // New line.
       for(int i = 0; i < reihe; i++){
            zahl += rand()%2;  // Changed line.

       }
       faecher[zahl]+= 1;

    }
    for(int j=0;j <=reihe;j++){
       for(int i=1;i<=faecher[j];i++){
        printf("#");
    }
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, for 300 balls and 10 rows, you may get an output like:

```
#
###########
##############################
#############################################################
####################################################################
######################################################################
########################################
###############
####
```